# Moving a file to a directory with spaces in the name

Tags: directory, mv

The destination directory is a directory with spaces in the name: `/opt/config/Sn Lk`
Now I wrote a script which moves a file from my directory to this directory, but the move fails
Although the echo of the command seems to be fine

```bash
workdir=/home/mydir
destdir="'opt/config/Sn Lk"
file=Al_10.txt

destination="$destdir/$file'"
echo "command = mv -v $workdir/$file $destination"
mv -v $workdir/$file $destination
```

result:

```bash
command = mv -v /home/mydir/Al_10.txt '/opt config/Sn Lk/Al_10.txt'
mv: target ‘Lk/Al_10.txt'’ is not a directory
```

How should the move-command be written?

Comment: This is some really weird bash code. Not sure I understand this: `destdir="'`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov That "opening" single quote seems to be closed in the `destination` variable, probably in the hope to protect the spaces in the directory names.

Comment: Drop the literal single quotes from the variables and double-quote the variable expansions in the `mv` command. See also the questions and answers marked as dupes.